# Add recurring date and time within range(StartDate and EndDate) using momentjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, momentjs

I need an array of recurring dates with time for every week within the start date and end date using moment.js or javascript.

For example:
Startdate: 2021-10-04T00:00:00Z
Enddate:  2021-10-31T00:00:00Z

let's say **2021-10-05T00:00:00Z** is a recurring date then output will be

**["2021-10-05T00:00:00Z", "2021-10-12T00:00:00Z", "2021-10-19T00:00:00Z", "2021-10-26T00:00:00Z"]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Date.getUTCDate()` and `Date.setUTCDate()` to advance a date by a number of days, in this case seven.

We can then use a while loop to populate the result array. I'm returning an array of Date objects here, one could use .toISOString() to convert to strings.

```js
let startDate = '2021-10-05T00:00:00Z';
let endDate = '2021-10-31T00:00:00Z';

function getWeeklyDates(start, end) {
    let date = new Date(start);
    const endDate = new Date(end);
    
    const result = [];
    while (date < endDate) {
        result.push(date);
        date = new Date(date);
        date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + 7);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getWeeklyDates(startDate, endDate).map(dt => dt.toISOString()))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

- start at the first recurring date
- add a week to the recurring date using `.add(1, 'weeks')` (see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/ )
- do this while recurring date < end date

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure js if you remove the "Z" add "+00:00" to all of your strings to make sure your timezone does not break this code.

```
let start = "2021-10-04T00:00:00+00:00";
let end = "2021-10-31T00:00:00+00:00";
let date = "2021-10-05T00:00:00+00:00";

start = new Date(start);
end = new Date(end);
date = new Date(date);
    
let dates = [];
if (date < start) {
    console.log("bad input")
} else {
    while (date.getTime() < end.getTime()) {
        dates.push(date.toISOString());
        date = new Date(date.getTime() + 604800000); // add a week in milliseconds
    }
}
```